# tuple of dictionary to list of tuples python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

i want to convert tuple of dictionary to list of tuple or list of list
and in my final list i only want values of dictionary not keys

tuple of dictionary =

```
({'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 29, 8), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'visit', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 55, 45), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '11-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 15, 17, 56), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '23-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 41, 5), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 42, 54), 'address_out': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import  datetime
data =({'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 29, 8), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'visit', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 55, 45), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '11-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 15, 17, 56), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '23-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 41, 5), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 42, 54), 'address_out': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India'})

result = []
for item in data:
     result.append(list(item.values()))
print ((result))
```

what is equivalent to:

```
print([list(item.values()) for item in data]) # List comprehension
```

output:

```
[['01-04-2019', 'attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 29, 8), '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', None, ''], ['01-04-2019', 'visit', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 55, 45), '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', None, ''], ['11-04-2019', 'attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 15, 17, 56), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', None, ''], ['23-04-2019', 'attendence', 'MCCuser0036', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 41, 5), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 42, 54), 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
data = ({'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 29, 8), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '01-04-2019', 'type': 'visit', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 15, 55, 45), 'address_in': '736, Aala Hazrat Rd, Jagruti Nagar, Nehru Nagar, Kurla East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400071, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '11-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 15, 17, 56), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': None, 'address_out': ''}, {'date_format': '23-04-2019', 'type': 'attendence', 'username': 'MCCuser0036', 'time_in': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 41, 5), 'address_in': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India', 'time_out': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 17, 42, 54), 'address_out': 'Kokri Agar Road, Koliwada, Kokri Agar, Sion, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400037, India'})
print([list(i.values()) for i in data])
```